# .Net get DateTimeFormat "G"

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker

I want to use DataGridView to display a date and a DateTimePicker to implement a filter. I want both of them to display the date time in the "G" formatted [Standard Date and Time Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Ideally, I would just do

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "G";
```

but that does not appear to work. (It literally displays the character "G" in the DateTimePicker.) I found the following workaround, but appears fragile and cumbersome to me.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns('G')[0];
dateTimePicker1.Value = now;

dataGridView.Rows.Add(now);
```

Any suggestions for improvements?

Edit: Added that I set dateTimePicker1.Format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
var formatInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
string pattern = formatInfo.ShortDatePattern + " " + formatInfo.LongTimePattern;
```

That follows what the [MSDN docs for 'G'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) state:

> The "G" standard format specifier represents a combination of the short date ("d") and long time ("T") patterns, separated by a space.

Comment: `formatInfo.ShortDatePattern + " " + formatInfo.LongTimePattern` is not much of an approvement over the `formatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns('G')[0]` he already has and claims works.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Well, it's an alternative. It may be more efficient too, but that's unlikely to be relevant.

Comment: I ended up sticking with my original solution. I appreciate the link to MSDN and another alternative solution. I hadn't found anything in my own searches about what "G" officially was defined as other than it was the default for [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

DateTimePicker doesn't support that. Check the values it supports for that property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx

Check if when you run that code, what's actually being put into the CustomFormat property of your picker isn't the long date and time pattern for the culture in your web.config.

**Important Edit**: Maybe simply setting the [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format.aspx) property to [DateTimePickerFormat.Long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepickerformat.aspx) will get what you want done.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the question (my bad), I set the Format property to DateTimePickerFormat.Custom. DateTimePickerFormat.Long only shows the date, but I want to display both the date and time.